# Проверка всех дочерних элементов узла дерева на наличие признака

Tags: c#

Есть дерево такого вида:

```
-Узел
    -Узел1
    -Узел2
        -Узел1
        -Узел2
           -Узелок
    -Узел3
    -Узел4
```

Каждый узел - класс:

```
class TreeNode
{
    public int Id {get; set;}

    pulic bool Property {get; set;}

    public IEnumerable<TreeNode> Children {get; set;}   
}
```

Нужно проверить, что хотя бы у одного из дочерних элементов (вложенность не ограничена), свойство `Property == true`.

```
public static bool HasProperty(this TreeNode self)
{
   if (self.Children.Any(c => c.Property == true))
       return true;
   else
   {
       foreach(var child in self.Children)
       {
           return child.HasChildrenWhithWardRegistration();
       }       
   }
   return false;
}

if(treeNode.HasProperty())
{
    //что-то выполняется
}
```

Такой вариант возвращает не все элементы, удовлетворяющие условию.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это легко сделать с помощью рекурсивного вызова, добавьте в свой класс следующий метод:

```
public bool HasProperty() => Property || Children.Any(x => x.HasProperty());
```

Если требуется проверять `Property` только у дочерних элементов, но не у самого элемента, можно написать такой метод:

```
public bool HasPropertyOfChildren() => Children.Any(x => x.HasProperty());
```

а `HasProperty()` сделать приватным (или оставить публичным - как сочтете нужным)

Answer (score 1):

```
...
else
{
  foreach(TreeNode child in self.Children)
  {
    if (child.HasChildrenWhithWardRegistration()) // не возвращать, если false !!!
      return true;
  }
}    
...
```

Comment: На шарпе, без Linq? Да вас засмеют :)

Answer (score 0):

Я бы сделал так. Завёл бы метод, возвращающий плоский список всех потомков, и применял бы к нему LINQ.

```
public static class TreeNodeExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<TreeNode> SelfAndDescendants(this TreeNode self) =>
        new[] { self }.Concat(self.Children.SelectMany(SelfAndDescendants));

    public static bool HasPropertyRec(this TreeNode self) =>
        self.SelfAndDescendants().Any(c => c.Property);
}
```